# Rows passed to html/bootstrap via json from java do not wrap across rows evenly

Tags: java, html, json, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am displaying images in a html/bootstrap page retrieved by java, passed by json. I am expecting the images to wrap evenly; however, there is a third row created with a single image and a fifth row with 3 extra images. If I change the zoom on the page, using the Chrome zoom function, the number of images on the row increases and do not wrap continuously. How do I get rows to wrap continuously?

java:

```
    String json = null;
    int i = 0;
    for (final YouthMember youthMember : youthMembers) {
        String image = youthMember.getPhotograph();
        String name = youthMember.getFirstname() + " " + youthMember.getSurname();

        if (i == 0){
            json = "<ul class='thumbnails'> <li class='span1 thumbnail'><a href='[[url]]'><img src=" +
                    image + " height='60' width='60' style='border-style: none' alt='person image' /></a>" +
                    "<div class='caption'> <p>" + name + "</p> </div></li>";
            i++;
        }else{
            json = json + "<li class='span1 thumbnail'><a href='[[url]]'><img src=" +
                    image + " height='60' width='60' style='border-style: none' alt='person image' /></a>" +
                    "<div class='caption'> <p>" + name + "</p> </div></li>";
        }

    }
    json = json + "</ul>";
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
```

ajax:

```
.done(function(responseJson1a) {
    dataType: "json";

    // JSON response to populate the image
    $(responseJson1a).appendTo($("#img-container"));
});
```

html:

```
   <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="selectForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-select">
                    <!-- Place for Captcha image -->
                    <div class="input-group" id="img-container">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /row -->
    </form>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have come up with that only contains 12 images in each row. However, when I adjust the page size it goes from 12 to 1 image per row. I expect it to be fluid and  go from 12 to 11 to 10 all the way down to 1 as the page decreases in size.

```
    String json = null;
    int i = 0;
    int col = 1;
    for (final YouthMember youthMember : youthMembers) {
        String image = youthMember.getPhotograph();
        String name = youthMember.getFirstname() + " " + youthMember.getSurname();

        if (i == 0){
            json = "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-1'><a href='CubAwardOverview.html?id=" + youthMember.getId() +
                    "'><img src=" +
                    image + " height='60' width='60' style='border-style: none' alt='person image' /></a>" +
                    "<div class='caption'> <p>" + name + "</p> </div></div>";
            i++; col++;
        }else{
            if (col > 12){
                json = json + "</div><div class='row'>";
                col = 1;
            }
            json = json + "<div class='col-md-1'><a href='CubAwardOverview.html?id=" + youthMember.getId() +
                    "'><img src=" +
                    image + " height='60' width='60' style='border-style: none' alt='person image' /></a>" +
                    "<div class='caption'> <p>" + name + "</p> </div></div>";
            col++;
        }

    }
    if (col > 0){
        json = json + "</div>";
    }
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
```